# Disable default nuxt.js routing

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Is it possible to disable the default routing of nuxt?

I have an spa, which should run on different subfolders/urls, but somehow the js is not kicking in properly. And i think because nuxt takes over the routing.

Or do you have other ideas how to get this running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nuxt's [implicit dynamic routing](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes) is a bit tricky to get used to.

It sounds like you'd appreciate [nuxt-community's router-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module), which allows you to specify routes in a `router.js` file like a standard Vue.js project.